# Run schedule in new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm querying an API to create a report and want to load that report 5 minutes later. I want to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` for that. As I don't want the Executor to block my thread, I'm creating a new thread for that, but am unsure if this is the correct way of doing this. Here's my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            log.info("Starting...");
            new RequestReport().runScheduledTask(requestId);
        }
    };
thread.start();
```

---

```
private void runScheduledTask(String requestId) {
    log.info("Starting five-minute countdown now...");
    ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        try {
            new GetReportList().run(requestId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    try {
        countdown.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        log.info("catched Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scheduler.shutdown();
}
```

Is there a better way to run a function 5 minutes after another? Is the way I'm doing this good? What should I change?

BTW, I'm using spring - is there something that could make that better?

Comment: If you are using Spring, you can also use `@Scheduled` [annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) to schedule a method invoke.

Comment: But ow can I make that dynamically? I need to run the task five minutes after the other - the execution time isn't known at program start. @SurajBajaj

Comment: @J.Doe Your `while (!countdown.isDone()) {}` busy loop is a really bad idea.

Comment: @J.Doe So is it just one time call five minutes after the other method call?

Comment: Can I just get rid of it without sideeffects?  @Kayaman

Comment: @J.Doe So it's not really "scheduled" call per say; just a delay of 5 minutes. I think you are better off just adding 5 min delay.

Comment: @J.Doe Read the javadocs. You're at least the third one I've seen who's written a busy loop instead of using `get()` to block until the computation is finished.

Comment: @Kayaman okay. Thank you, I will read it again more closely!

Comment: Why destroy the scheduler?

Comment: @jameslarge this is my first time using it.. Can you explain why not ?

Comment: @Kayaman - am I interpreting it wrong? Edited the question

Comment: @J.Doe Well that gets rid of the nasty busy loop. Your `Thread` thingie is probably unnecessary too. A `ScheduledExecutorService` already runs in its own threads, of course then you can't call `get()` since it will block.

Comment: @JDoe, just trying to understand what you want to accomplish.  Your method is named `runScheduledTask()`, not `runScheduledTaskAndThenDestroyScheduler()`.  The second name would be better because that's a more accurate description of what the method actually does.  But it would be far better to design your program so that the method does not need to have "AndThen..." in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` is a good choice, but you use it incorrectly:

First of all, you don't need to create a `Thread` just to schedule a task from it. It adds nothing to the functionality, only wastes resources.

Second, after calling `shutdown()` your `scheduler` will no longer accept tasks, which is bad if you need to generate more than one report.

Third, since your code does nothing after the task completion, you don't need to call `get()` at all.

So, the only code you need is:

```
scheduler.schedule(() -> {
    try {
        new GetReportList().run(requestId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

It will schedule a task and release your thread immediately. The task will be executed five minutes later in a separate thread that is managed by `scheduler`.

If you need some control on the scheduled tasks (check their states, cancel them etc.), you can obtain `Future` from `schedule()` and save it somewhere, but based on the code from your question, you don't need it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed! Spring didn't start until `get()` was called, but your explanation makes much much more sense...

Comment: @J.Doe, could you, please, amplify a bit on "Spring didn't start until get() was called"? I don't think this code can somehow affect Spring. Maybe it was something else that prevented it from starting? When you call `get()` the thread blocks and waits for the task completion (which takes at least five minutes). I don't think you need it in your program (at least it doesn't follow from your description) because your `GetReportList.run()` returns nothing.

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said. I meant before I did the changes you proposed. Now it works perfectly fine - but it didn't when I had `get()` in the function (without creating a new thread) as it blocked it. Your answer works perfectly!

Comment: Oh, well then. I didn't understand your first comment correctly, my bad. I'm glad the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to be more 'correct' about the code, you could separate the RequestReport into it's own class implementing the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, and pass along an instance of said class to the Thread's constructor

Comment: A class should only `implement Runnable` if there is some obvious, unambiguous explanation for what it means to `run()` an instance of the class.  What does it mean to run a RequestReport?  Does it mean _generate_ the report?  Does it mean _print_ the report?  Generate _and_ print the report?  Something else altogether?  If there's no single, obvious meaning, then IMO, it's better to implement the `run()` method with a lambda expression or, with an anonymous inner class as in the OP's example.